# Retrieving packets by tshark until it gets a specific packet?

Tags: tshark

While using `tshark`, I want to capture a packet that contains a specific string.

After executing `tshark`, I want it to stop receiving packets immediately when it receives a packet that contains the specific string and return it.

What parameters should I use to do this operation?

Comment: @pchaigno I couldn't find anything so I asked the question without any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [trigcap](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=trigcap.c;h=0d7cf9ea3467fb63624f16c27a55184876c01e7b;hb=HEAD), which is part of the Wireshark project, but not currently being shipped to my knowledge because it apparently doesn't work on Windows and may have problems on other platforms now too since it hasn't seen any active development in quite a long time AFAIK.

You can try to compile it yourself to see if it meets your needs.  Read more about it at:

- [Bug 2039 - Triggered Capture](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2039)
- [what is the work of trigcap?](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/6656/what-is-the-work-of-trigcap)

If you're on Windows, you might want to take a look at the [dumpcap.bat](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=dumpcap.bat) file posted on the Wireshark wiki [Tools](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) page.

All of these solutions rely on BPF ([pcap-filters](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html)), so whatever string you're looking for as your stop condition needs to somehow be manipulated into that format, which may not be easy to do.

Comment: I'll try trigcap. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Christopher Maynard There's a typo on BPF (which I can't fix because the edit is too small).

Comment: @pchaigno, sorry I don't understand your comment.  What BFP typo, where?

Comment: It's BPF not BFP. It stands for Berkeley Packet Filter.

Comment: Indeed, it is BPF and that's what I intended to write.  I thought you were referring to an actual BPF **filter** somewhere.  Oh well, thanks for catching it.  Apparently I typed it incorrectly twice, once in the answer and once in my last comment.  It's fixed in the answer now, but I can no longer correct the comment.

Comment: No problem. I guess a double typo doesn't hurt anyone as long as it's not in a password verification field...